# In R, how do I create an environment in a function so that its child-functions can see it?

Tags: r, function, environment

If I create the "outside" environment in the main R code below, both step1() and step2(), which is called from step1(), can see it.  But if step1() creates an "inside" environment, step2() cannot see that.  How do I create an environment in a function so that its child-functions can see it?

```
rm(list=ls())

step1 <- function() {
  ansout <- exists("outside", mode = "environment")
  ansin <- exists("inside", mode = "environment")
  cat("From step1, ansout = ", ansout, ", ansin = ", ansin, "\n")
  inside <- new.env()
  step2()
  return()
}

step2 <- function() {
  ansout <- exists("outside", mode = "environment")
  ansin <- exists("inside", mode = "environment")
  cat("From step2, ansout = ", ansout, ", ansin = ", ansin, "\n")
  return()
}

outside <- new.env()
step1()

# Output:
# From step1, ansout =  TRUE , ansin =  FALSE 
# From step2, ansout =  TRUE , ansin =  FALSE
```

Comment: What is your overall goal here? You're asking about environments but I don't think the scoping behaviour you're describing is different with environments than any other object. Is there a reason you can't pass `inside` as an argument to `step2()`?

Comment: This may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe the overall *x* problem and not only your proposed *y* solution. Simply, what is the true need for your use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions enclose the environment where they’re defined. In other words, a function has access to objects that exist in the environment where it was defined, but doesn’t necessarily have access to objects that exist in the environment it’s called from.

Your functions are both defined in the global environment, so only have access to `outside`.  If you define `step2()` within `step1()`, it will have access to `inside`.

```
step1 <- function() {
  step2 <- function() {
    ansout <- exists("outside", mode = "environment")
    ansin <- exists("inside", mode = "environment")
    cat("From step2, ansout = ", ansout, ", ansin = ", ansin, "\n")
    return()
  }
  ansout <- exists("outside", mode = "environment")
  ansin <- exists("inside", mode = "environment")
  cat("From step1, ansout = ", ansout, ", ansin = ", ansin, "\n")
  inside <- new.env()
  step2()
  return()
}

outside <- new.env()
step1()
# From step1, ansout =  TRUE , ansin =  FALSE 
# From step2, ansout =  TRUE , ansin =  TRUE
```

If nesting the function isn’t an option, you can add an argument to `step2()` to pass the `inside` environment as @SamR suggested. Or you can `get()` objects from the calling environment using `parent.frame()`.

```
step1 <- function() {
  ansout <- exists("outside", mode = "environment")
  ansin <- exists("inside", mode = "environment")
  cat("From step1, ansout = ", ansout, ", ansin = ", ansin, "\n")
  inside <- new.env()
  step2()
  return()
}

step2 <- function() {
  inside <- get("inside", envir = parent.frame())
  ansout <- exists("outside", mode = "environment")
  ansin <- exists("inside", mode = "environment")
  cat("From step2, ansout = ", ansout, ", ansin = ", ansin, "\n")
  return()
}

outside <- new.env()
step1()
# From step1, ansout =  TRUE , ansin =  FALSE 
# From step2, ansout =  TRUE , ansin =  TRUE
```